# Area51 Badge Request: Following Through

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, area-51, badge-request

I think that we should have a badge for people who completed their commitments in Area51. Maybe a bronze badge for doing it once and then a silver badge or something for doing it, I don't know, how about 5 times or so? What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good idea.  Maybe 1, 5, 10?

Answer (score 4):

I'd say just make it a silver badge for following through three times, in keeping with the number of commitments that we can extend.

That requires about ~6 weeks of time on the part of the user, which is average for the time needed to earn most other silver badges (if not less). Even if active in 3 betas at once, the time consumed (in hours spent by the user) is still pretty much the same.

A gold badge perhaps for following through on 9 sites.

At the least, following through  gets you four things:

- A silver beta badge
- One step closer to another silver badge (or possibly earn it)
- Some more rep to put behind your commitments
- One step closer to a gold badge (or possibly earn it)

Answer (score 0):

How about:
Gold Badge: 
Achieved follow through within the first day of the private beta.

Silver Badge:
Achieved follow through within the first three days of the private beta.

Bronze Badge:
Achieved follow through some time during the 60/90 days of the beta.

Comment: Small nitpick, Jeff has stated that it's not possible to follow through until the second day of private beta at the earliest.

Comment: not a bad idea but I don't want it to be a "fastest gun" sort of thing. It's a marathon, not a sprint.